# how to set emulator's keyboard

Tags: android, emulation

I tried to use keyboard to control emulator, I want use enter to open application,but it's not work.
I tried for some configs,I only found “default.keyset” file, like

> **BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER  Keypad_5
>  BUTTON_DPAD_UP      Keypad_8
>
>   BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT    Keypad_4
>  BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT   Keypad_6
>
>   BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN    Keypad_2**

maybe change `<B>BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER  Keypad_5</b>` can config,but I don't konw how to config.

hope to get some advice!

=================================
**The problem has been treated**
**open "default.keyset" file, find "BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER  Keypad_5" and change to "BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER  Enter"**

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. I had the same problem after upgrading to Tools version 20. I had to Edit the AVD to add an option as follows:

From Eclipse, Go to AVD Mananger.
Select the particular AVD and click on Edit
Go to the Hardware section, click on New.
Select the Property Name : Keyboard Support
By default, it is added with a value of 'no'. Just click on the value column and change it to 'yes'.
Click on Edit AVD again.
This will add a property hw.keyboard=yes in config.ini file for the AVD.

Comment: thanks, I just successed,“default.keyset” file has a line "TOGGLE_FULLSCREEN   Alt-Enter",I consider “Enter” maybe map to the key "enter",so I tried and successed!